# Formal definition for sine and cosine

Tags: trigonometry, angle

I stumbled this [proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sine_and_Cosine_are_Periodic_on_Reals) for the period of $2\pi$ for sine and cosine on $\mathbb{R}$. The characterization of sine and cosine relies on these properties

$$\cos(a + b) = \cos(a)\cos(b) - \sin(a)\sin(b)$$
$$\sin(a + b) = \sin(a)\cos(b) + \cos(a)\sin(b)$$
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(h)}{h} = 1$$

And the initial conditions $\cos(0) = 1$ and $\sin(0) = 0$. From this point, we can compute the derivatives for sine and cosine so that $(\cos(x))' = -\sin(x)$ and $(\sin(x))' = \cos(x)$ useful to derive the power series. It is no surprise that the power series yield two periodic functions with a period of $2\pi$ as they parametrize the unit circle.

Consider this circle with the bounded sector area in green:

[image]

Defining a totally new unit for angles (denoted $₳$) as a bounded sector area $A$ over the radius $r$ squared such as

$$₳ = \frac{A}{r^2}$$

We notice this new unit satisfies $360^\circ = 2\pi = \pi₳$ so we must naturally define two function in place of sine and cosine, namely $c$ and $s$ which are periodic of period $\pi$, but we see that this two functions also preserve the properties above

$$c(a + b) = c(a)c(b) - s(a)s(b)$$
$$s(a + b) = s(a)c(b) + c(a)s(b)$$
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{s(h)}{h} = 1$$

And the initial conditions $c(0) = 1$ and $s(0) = 0$ are also satisfied. However, although our new unit for angle definition defines a complete revolution in a period of $\pi$, we would still get power series for a period of $2\pi$ which means two revolutions for one period.

Fundamentally, the natural unit would be twice the bounded sector area $A$ over the radius $r$ to have one revolution for one period.

So what really defines sine and cosine, the radian and the unit circle or the properties above?

---

Please do not mark this as a duplicate, I have read other answers but none of them really solved my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $s$ function is basically $\sin 2x$, so that it has a period of $\pi$.

But $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin2h}{h}=2\ne1,$$
so that property no longer holds.

As to "what really defines them", it doesn't matter. If you take the power series definition or the differential equation definition, it makes the analysis easy. If you appreciate the intuition more, start with the circle. When I teach my students, I start from the circle in [my notes](https://drmenguin.com/files/trig.pdf), and then in a [remark](https://drmenguin.com/files/trig.pdf#lemma.2) I show that this is the same as the power series definition.

What's important isn't what defines them, but what *characterises* them, i.e., what properties uniquely capture their behaviour. You can start either with the properties you listed, or with the differential equation, or the power series definition, or $\Re e^{i\theta}$ and $\Im e^{i\theta}$ for instance. These all uniquely determine the standard $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions.

Comment: That's true. But geometrically, this limit holds if you consider the bounded area, you can compute this because you already know the definition for sine derived from the properties above.

Comment: @eigenslacker What do you mean "geometrically, the limit holds"? It either holds or it doesn't. Since your limit is different from 1, it's not the same function.

Comment: This limit is often proved by just inspecting the unit circle and stating that the angle is close to zero and so the sine of the angle is, but if you consider the bounded area, you could have the same intuition (which is wrong, of course) and still derive this limit.

Comment: @eigenslacker That is why heuristics are dangerous in calculus, I don't like them because they only happen to work for specific instances. That reasoning is 100% wrong. It's like saying $x$ and $2x$ both go to zero at roughly the same rate, so $x\approx 2x$ for small $x$, and $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2x}{x} = 1$. (Which is wrong, it's actually $2$).

Comment: So have I still not answered your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106325/discussion-between-eigenslacker-and-luke-collins).

Answer (score 1):

Combined as a complex relation, the first two equations read

$$e^{i(a+b)}=e^{ia}e^{ib},$$ which can be generalized as

$$e^{z_a+z_b}=e^{z_a}e^{z_b}$$ by introducing real parts.

Now, the functional equation

$$f(z_a+z_b)=f(z_a)f(z_b)$$ does define an exponential function. Anyway, this necessitates some smoothness condition on $f$ (which I don't know exactly).

The condition on the limit can be seen as a "normalization", which makes the base of the exponential the number $e$.

Comment: Very nice, however it requires a prior definition for sine and cosine since it involves the Euler formula, a good start for defining sine and cosine would be to start from the unit circle cartesian equation, this was more or less the main question I had.

Comment: @eigenslacker: no, it does not. The sine and cosine are just the real and imaginary part of the exponential for a pure imaginary argument.

Comment: I don't understand how you can involve the exponential function in a topic about trigonometry and the unit circle without requiring the Euler formula. My question was about the radian definition, and defining two functions that would yield the x and y coordinates of any point on the unit circle.

Comment: @eigenslacker: your title said "Formal definition for sine and cosine".

Comment: You’re right, it should have been “Intuitive definition for sine and cosine” as I was trying to have the formal definition of sine and cosine only from the basic properties of the unit circle.